# PHP Resque Worker not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-resque

I want to use php_resque(https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) for my codeigniter project. 
This is the function 'test' to create a new job.

```
public function test() {
    $this->load->library('My_Job');

    Resque::setBackend('localhost:6379');

    $args = array(
        'name' => 'Chris'
    );

    $token = Resque::enqueue('default', 'My_Job', $args, true);

    $status = new Resque_Job_Status($token);

    Resque::dequeue('default', ['My_Job' => $token]);
}
```

And this is the worker library code

```
putenv("VVERBOSE=1");
putenv("LOGGING=1");
putenv("QUEUE=*");
class My_Job {

    public function perform($args) {

        $this->load->model('M_sms');
        $this->M_sms->ins_msg();
    }

}
```

when i call 'test'(localhost/project_folder/controller/test), the 'perform' function in the worker(My_Job.php) is not loading. And Job status is 1. what is wrong here ?

## EDIT

when i used following code to debug

`VERBOSE=1 QUEUE=default php resque.php`

it says Could not find job class

Comment: Put code instead of images

Comment: updated to code @wolfgang1983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code, the problem is, the worker do not know the location of job class. As i mentioned above, i am getting status 1 (STATUS_WAITING), which means 'Job is still queued'. This occurred to me because i tried to load the job class as a library in my codeigniter project.

```
$this->load->library('My_Job');
```

Now i changed my code according to this tutorial  [Programe Veryday](http://programeveryday.com/post/message-queues-php-and-resque/)

This tutorial explain step by step procedure to set up [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque)

Answer (score 0):

you have to include your application autoloader:

`QUEUE=* VVERBOSE=1 REDIS_BACKEND=localhost:9999 APP_INCLUDE=./path/to/loader.php php resque.php`

http://kamisama.me/2012/10/12/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-4-managing-worker/